# Rails 3 my custom BufferedLogger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to define a custom logger for my Rails 3 app, in a way that it does not replace the original logger (I still make use of its information).

I assumed that I could define in a lib a class that inherited BufferedLogger as I've seen on some blogs. Then I would instantiate a variable to represent my logger, on the end of my application.rb with those lines:

```
require 'smart_logger.rb'
sl = SmartLogger.new("log/soccer.log")
```

And in my controller (as models and views) I would be able to use:

```
sl.warn("Tentativa #{session[:login_number]} de fazer login do IP#{request.remote_ip}, email:#{@user_session.try :email}, senha: #{@user_session.try :password}. ")
```

My question is how can I achieve to have my custom logger available application wide and flushing properly? That would be sort of a parallel logger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better describing, its more like an User-Action-Logger, targeting Data Minning.

btw: I guess it has a great performance :)

http://fabianosoriani.wordpress.com/2010/11/01/rails-user-action-logger

Answer (score 0):

Here is a gem that makes log output customization really easy in Rails3:
https://github.com/johmas/itslog